# Iterating & Concatenating 2 lists is taking up huge memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, iterator

In Python 3, I am trying to generate a sequence in this format from 4 lists

```
<yyyymmdd>-<1-200>-<1-20>-<1-13000>

20161201-1-1-1
20161201-1-1-2
20161201-1-1-3
..
..
20161201-1-2-1
20161201-1-2-2
..
..
20161201-2-1-1
20161201-2-1-2
..
20161202-1-1-1
20161202-1-1-2
..
..
20190701-200-20-13000
```

first list is in a date range of `<yyyymmdd to yyyymmdd>`, the remaining 3 lists are in ranges `<1-200> <1-20> and <1-13000>`.

All list values are in str format.

Now I'm trying to this the following:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

all_dates = [d.strftime('%Y%m%d') for d in pd.date_range('20160119','20191226')]
all_users = list(range(0,200))
all_products = list(range(0,15))
all_customers = list(range(0,13000))

date_user_product_map = []
date_user_product_customer_map = []

for pair in itertools.product(all_dates,all_users, all_products):
    date_user_product_map.append('-'.join(pair))

for pair in itertools.product(date_user_product_map,all_customers):
    date_user_product_customer_map.append('-'.join(pair))
```

The first concatenation of 3 lists is fast and low on memory.
The second concatenation is just taking up huge memory and is getting killed.

I tried running this on a 48 gig RAM system too but it seems no amount of memory is enough for this to run.

I would like some help on solving this issue and also understanding why this needs so much memory. What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
**(my requirement)**

So, I have couple of dataframes which have few columns whose values in the format of the -<1-200>-<1-20>-<1-13000> which is taking up to much space And hence I want to create the list of all possible values and then enumerate over and create a dictionary like below:

-<1-200>-<1-20>-<1-13000>

20161201-1-1-1 : 0
20161201-1-1-2 : 1
20161201-1-1-3 : 2
..
..
20190701-200-20-12999 : n-1
20190701-200-20-13000 : n

and then replace the values of the dataframes to 1,2... n,n-1.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There are over 1000 dates in that list, so you seem to be compiling a list of 40 billion+ strings, each of which will take about 30 bytes, so you are getting into the terabyte range. Why not make a generator? Do you really need all those strings in memory at once?

Comment: replace all the lists with generators

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question with my actual requirement. Please have a look.

Comment: The only purpose of your dictionary seems to be to "enumerate" (assign serial numbers to) the concatenated strings. If this understanding is correct, I suggest you drop the idea of having that dictionary. You can always enumerate on the fly using `enumerate()`.

Comment: @fountainhead a sample code will help. I want the serial numbers to be same across the data frames for the concatenated values.

i.e.
I want to replace all `*20161201-1-1-2*` in all dataframes to `*1*`.
Similarly replace `*20161201-1-1-3*` with `*2*`.

The reason is, I will use this column to merge between the dataframes and also later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to convert those ranges into lists.

You should do something like this:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

all_dates = (d.strftime('%Y%m%d') for d in pd.date_range('20160119','20191226'))
all_users = range(0,200)
all_products = range(0,15)
all_customers = range(0,13000)

date_user_product_pairs = ( '-'.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(all_dates,all_users, all_products))

date_user_product_customer_pairs = ( '-'.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(date_user_product_map,all_customers))
```

then you can use those pair generators to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know how I can use this to solve my purpose.
I've updated my question with my actual requirement. Please have a look.

Comment: you can use those pair generator fuctions to make the dict

Comment: But even then, doesn't creating a dictionary later won't have similar memory issues?

Comment: No , you just loop over those two , and write them to file system instead of storing it in memory

Comment: and if you want more computation on that , then load them again using a generator , do the computation in loop and write it back to file system , never store in RAM  in any step

Comment: use json.dumps and json.loads for storing and loading maps

Comment: My requirement is: I want to replace the concatenated strings in multiple data frames with their respective serial numbers. I want the serial numbers to be same across the data frames for the same concatenated values. i.e. I want to replace all *20161201-1-1-2* in all dataframes to *1*. Similarly replace *20161201-1-1-3* with *2*. The reason is, I will use this column to merge between the dataframes and also later. The reason for this is am changing the strings to integers which I guess will reduce the size.

Comment: @AvinashSonee: Hope your approach (of replacing strings with integers) will cope with the possibility of new customers or new products getting introduced in future. You might want to think that through. Unless of course, this whole program isn't intended for real "production" use.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a single generator expression:

```
sequences = ('-'.join(str(x) for x in p) for p in itertools.product(all_dates,all_users,all_products, all_customers))
```

Used like:

```
>>> for _ in range(10): print(next(sequences))

20160119-0-0-0
20160119-0-0-1
20160119-0-0-2
20160119-0-0-3
20160119-0-0-4
20160119-0-0-5
20160119-0-0-6
20160119-0-0-7
20160119-0-0-8
20160119-0-0-9
```